# Some process/service/driver repeatedly presses F5

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I have the strangest problem that started 2 days ago (Windows7, 64bit). SOMETHING causes my F5 key to be constantly pressed. Rebooting helps, but only for a while, it keeps coming back to that.

So far I've tried to disconnect and reconnect the keyboard (physically), however, disconnecting the keyboard doesn't actually do anything. Reconnecting it back again, causes the F5-pressing to stop, but not for very long (seconds/minutes).

I'd really like to avoid a binary search for the programs (process closing/keyboard switching/etc) before I can, at the very least, identify the source of the keypress. Is there an application that can show me what is causing a key press? E.g is it the keyboard driver, or some process that executes SendKey repeatedly for reasons unknown.

Thanks!

P.S FYI, having F5 causes the strangest side effects. Task Manager refreshes very very quickly (as F5 is refresh), the desktop is constantly flickering and all the browsers stop working as they keep trying to refresh. I was lucky to find out what the heck is happening only because I started notepad and saw that current date/time started to appear constantly. If not that, I'd still be wondering.

P.S.S Another tidbit that might turn useful for anyone experiencing a similar issue: The problem described, turned my workstation effectively unworkable, as you can understand from the symptoms described above, the best solution I found so far is using AutoHotKey with the following script:

```
!F5::
+F5::
^F5::
F5::
return
```

Which effectively disabled F5 key system-wide. It works great and almost without any CPU loss, still, of course, I have to get the issue solved.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/125392/determine-what-is-invoking-refresh-f5-in-winxp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it WAS a hardware problem. As I said before, the problem persisted when I plugged out the keyboard, HOWEVER, I forgot I have more than 1 keyboard connected - I have a second media keyboard which sits under the table and is wireless. Apparently the cat pressed the button sometime during the night and it got stuck =\.

Thanks for trying to help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a replacement keyboard?

Comment: I will try that. Will let you know how it went. I wanted to avoid it as I had no near keyboard replacement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a Konica Minolta Printer driver do something like this. It was a 'Universal' driver. needless to say we restored the original driver that came with the device.

Comment: Hmmm.. Strange. How did you discover it was that driver?

Comment: It was the only thing changed on the server before the strangeness started. You even hear the click. Procmon from sysinternals confirmed the finding. 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Confused. How can I use process monitor to monitor which process/driver presses a key?

Comment: We noticed when the screen refreshed, what processes were actually running. We could NOT see the keyboard buffer since most of those utilities get detected a keyboard loggers in our anitvirus program.